# Scrolling is going too fast

Tags: java, algorithm, lwjgl

I used delta based off the LWJGL tutorials and it works (I get 16 or 17 delta) but everything is scrolling nonstop.

Here's how I render things:

```
public class Game {


    int camX;
    int camY;

    float dx = 0.35f;
    float dy = 0.35f;

    public void init()
    {
    }

    public void update(int delta)
    {
        getInput(delta);
    }

    public void render(int delta)
    {
        glTranslatef(-camX, -camY, 0);
        Artist.drawQuad(10, 10);        //draws at 0,0 with width and height of 10
    }



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void getInput(int delta)
    {
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
            camX-=1;

    }


}
```

EDIT: it seems when I `glTranslatef();` it moves fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getInput(int delta)
{
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
        camX-=1;
}
```

Is usually:

```
float camX;
float speedPerWholeSecond = 1;
public void getInput(float fractionalElapsedSeconds)
{
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
        camX -= (speedPerWholeSecond  * fractionalElapsedSeconds);
}
```

This calculation is made FrameRate times per second.
You can still snap to integer increments:

```
glTranslatef(int)-camX, (int)-camY, 0);
```

If Delta must be an int:

```
float camX;
float speedPerWholeSecond = 1;
public void getInput(int delta)
{
    //delta = 16(ms) (60 fps)
    float fDelta = (delta / 1000.0f);
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
        camX -= (speedPerWholeSecond * fDelta);
}
```

Edit: Since this is your top-level Game object:

```
public void update(int delta)
{
    float fDelta = (delta / 1000.0f);
    getInput(fDelta);
    //Future stuff below
    //camera.update(fDelta);
    //terrain.update(fDelta);
    //player.update(fDelta);
}
```

(Render() also)

Edit2:

```
public void getInput(float delta)
{
  float deltaX = 0;
  float deltaY = 0;
  float amountX = (1 * delta / 1000.0f); //For separate X and Y speeds
  float amountY = (1 * delta / 1000.0f); //For separate X and Y speeds
  if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
    deltaX -= amountX;
  if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S))
    deltaY += amountY;
  if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D))
    deltaX += amountX;
  if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W))
    deltaY -= amountY;
  if(deltaX || deltaY)
  {
    camX = deltaX;
    camY = deltaY;
  }
  else
  {
    camX = 0;
    camY = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't help: http://pastebin.com/SiTjSQAh

Comment: @CodeOfGenius, did you scale delta before the call to update()? Try this for right now, camX -= (1  * delta / 1000.0f); - Changing delta to float doesn't change the value it holds. Update() is being passed an int.

Comment: In other words, that number (delta / 1000) will be used elsewhere, so you should go up one level and (un)scale it in the method that calls Update() and Render(). The parameter's value is typically 0.0166666f for 60fps.

Comment: Other, other words: You are adding 1 per-frame, instead of 1 per-second

Comment: @CodeOfGenius, hey check the edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure it's working. It takes several seconds before it starts moving. When it does move it doesn't stop either. http://pastebin.com/CRwmUX0c . If your interested and/or have the time to check how I calculate delta: http://pastebin.com/VfD5ghdM

Comment: You are re-integrating camX each frame, then re-integrating that into the matrix each frame; that means you are accelerating camX rather than setting it to a velocity. Refer to Edit2 for solution; camX/Y are either speedX/Y or 0. After this edit, you may need to adjust the speed factors (1) to get desirable results.

Comment: glTranslatef translates the matrix on top of the stack and leaves it there. It does not create a new translation-only matrix and push it onto the stack.

Comment: if(deltaX || deltaY) ? I'm not sure what you meant by that. In Java || is the or operator.

Comment: if ((deltaX != 0) || (deltaY != 0))

Comment: Java could be different, but I know || to be "or else". If deltaX != 0, the second half will not even be evaluated.